# Normalized database search query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in MySQL:

`users`

```
Columns:
    1. id
    2. username
    3. email
    4. password
```

`users_roles`

```
Columns:
    1. id
    2. user
    3. role
```

I have roles saved in an array like this:

```
array(
    '1' => 'Carpenter',
    '2' => 'Plumber',
    '3' => 'Hair Stylist'
)
```

In the search form, I have checkboxes for the above roles with their IDs. In the form processing script, I have `$roles` array having the checked roles.

How do I query the database to search for users with one of the roles of Carpenter, Plumber, Hair Stylist?

**Update** : Here's the query I came up with:

```
SELECT `users`.`id` 
FROM `users`
WHERE 
    `users`.`id` IN 
    ( 
    SELECT `user` FROM `users_roles` WHERE `role` IN ( 1, 2, 3 ) 
    ) 
GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? Or is this bound to cause some server overload?

Comment: Your database does not seem normalized. The role definitions you keep in an array should be an actual table in your database (e.g. `roles`), and `users_roles` should reference both `users` and `roles`.

Comment: Oh. That's easy for me to add since the app is still in development stage. What should the query be, after I add the table and rows?

Comment: Your question is overly broad. Any possible answer would be a complete solution, which you will not learn anything from. You should read [the docs about joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html), it might answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Tables are "user" (as you have), user_roles (as you have) and then "user_roles_link" which contains the user_id and role_id linking the two.

To get the user that belong to a specific role, start with the table you want to primarily get the data from (in this case "users") and then "join" the user_id to the user_role_link" table, and then from that into the user_role table (linked by role_id). Restrict (WHERE) by the role_name.

As lanzz said, anything more is really writing the entire solution - but that should give you enough to work out the approach.

---

Edit: when you've got that bit working (i.e. the JOINS), remember to check out indexes. Important with the relations (joins) to make them fast.

Comment: `user_roles_link`? Instead `user_roles` should be refactored to contain only `user_id` and `role_id` and `UNIQUE KEY` on both these columns

Comment: Nope - to nomalize correctly you'll have three tables. Users (id + name + etc), the Roles (id + name + etc) and a linking table (many->many relationship, containing user_id and role_id).

Comment: Yes, dude, exactly 3 tables: `users`, `roles` and `users_roles` (refactotored as I said). =) `users_roles` is that "linking table" you're talking about.

Comment: Yep - and those are better names IMO, but didn't want to suggest it to avoid confusing the answer, but you have it sussed. So just the SQL to work out (follow the link on joins) and you're done. :)

Answer (score 1):

Better way to do this will be to add a table called roles

Table Roles

Columns

1. ID
2. Role

Then have another table to map user's to their roles

Table User_Roles
Columns

1. User_ID
2. Role_ID

User_Roles table will be able to store multiple roles for a user, like:

User_ID  RoleID
1        2
1        4

Then in your queries you can use some [joining](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) magic. Though i cant provide a more elaborate answer, as Question is quite broad.